# How do I add information to my Heroku database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, procfile

I am currently trying to deploy a Node.js application to Heroku. The website is working until I try and login or do other operations that call the database. I have the database attached and keep getting the `Error: write EPIPE` error. From what I can tell from my research, it seems like I need a `worker` process. Right now I have my `web` process as `./bin/www` and I do not know what to set my worker process to. I tried setting it to the same thing, but the app crashes. How do I add information from my app to a Heroku database?

Comment: What is an Heroku database?

Comment: @MattWay It's a Postgres database hosted on Heroku.